# Click event is not triggered in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding a click event with an elementid like this:

```
 $("#a").bind({click : dosomestuff });
```

After that when I am trying to trigger it with the `.trigger()` function like this:

```
   $("#a").trigger("click");
```

The function is not triggering. Can anybody tell me the problem?

Comment: works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/115/... do you `#a` append to dom after page load

Comment: Works okay here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nfrv4/

Comment: You most likely didn't put this code to be executed after the  `"#a"` element exists. Another possibility is `dosomestuff` actually not doing anything. This being some bug in jQuery itself is most far fetched and should be explored last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may don't put you code within

```
$(function() {

});
```

or

if your `#a` in dynamic then try

```
$('document').on('click', '#a', dosomestuff); // it would be better to 
                                              // replace document with 
                                              // `#a`'s parent
```

Comment: `$('#a').on('click', dosomstuff);` won't do anything the op's code isn't already doing.. perhaps you mean `$(document).on( "click", "#a", dosomstuff)` (`.live`-equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

A few things that could be wrong in order of likelihood:

- You didn't put this code inside `$(function() { ... });`, so the element wasn't ready yet.
- The element doesn't exist (you can check this via your developer console)
- jQuery isn't loaded
- You're deliberately creating the element later; use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to bind click event to an anchor tag then you should use

```
 $("a").bind('click',function(){
     //do your stuff here
 } );
```